# Gradle project refresh failed with no error details

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I was working on a project and updated the Android Studio to 1.5 beta. Also I installed android sdks 22 and 23 via SDK manager. After restart the Gradle is failing to refresh without giving any error details.
Here is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.projname"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
}
```

Whats wrong with this?

Edit: Android Studio Version details
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: change your project build tool version to 23 and see

Comment: I tried that, but no luck

Comment: If you don't have standalone gradle, install it and then run "gradle clean build --stacktrace" from commandline. If there is something wrong with your script, it should tell you.